# Loop IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python

I have this error

```
onecheck(sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2],sys.argv[3]) 
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I try to make loop a python script .

This is code :

```
with open(file) as k:
     for line in k:
         aa, bb, cc = line.split(':')
         time.sleep(5)
         os.system("python checkfile.py " + cc + " " + aa + " " + bb)
```

Last line from file is working

Comment: before the part where you split, print the line and make sure that there are actually at least two `:` in there. If there is lots of output, you can also test it in an if-clause with `if line.count(':') < 2:  # whoops`

Comment: may be some variable got blank. Can you print aa, bb, cc

Comment: Why are you calling one Python script from another via `os.system`? Why not import the function and call it directly?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Jo7sO

Comment: aa
bb
cc

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "checkfile.py", line 306, in <module>
    onecheck(sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2],sys.argv[3])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: I can print aa, bb, cc :-w

Comment: The error is in 'checkfile.py', add `print repr(sys.argv)`. On start on 'checkfile.py' to be sure the argument are send correctly

Comment: But last line from txt file is working

Comment: How can the last line of **txt** file work?

Comment: Look here : https://imgur.com/a/UChta

Answer (score 0):

Why don't import checkfile directly, don't run via `os.system()`

If you are looking for a non-blocking way to execute your function in `checkfile.py`, look at :

- https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html
- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm

:

```
import checkfile


with open(file) as k:
    for line in k:
        ltab = line.split(':')
        if len(ltab) > 2:
            time.sleep(5)
            checkfile.my_func(ltab[0], ltab[1], ltab[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

**Issue**: You're getting any of the `aa`, `bb`, `cc` empty at:

```
aa, bb, cc = line.split(':')
```

**Suggestion**: In addition to above comments, you can also put your call in length check:

```
if len(sys.argv)== 4:  # index 0 - 3 
    onecheck(sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2],sys.argv[3])
```